# How to get the playback element to be present in all the screens of my flutter application?

Tags: flutter

I am creating a music player in flutter, the application has multiple screens and I need the playback element to be present in all the screens of my application, how would this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

this package can be used.
https://pub.dev/packages/music_player.
Check for tutorials in youtube